# Какую модель структуры БД выбрать, чтобы Django справился?

Tags: json, django, rest

Задача: вести учет **движения** чего-нибудь. К примеру, бункеров.

1. Бункеры перемещаются между разными объектами
2. Важно иметь возможность получить следующие отчеты:

   А) В одной строке Объект "исходящий" и объект "назначения". В примере на картинке передвижение бункеров между морскими портами.
   [image: Пример отчета]

   тут порты и корабли это **объекты**
   Б) Отчет по количеству бункеров на данный момент на каждом из объектов
   В) отчет по количеству объектов на каждом **типе объекта** (наш порт, корабль, порт заказчика)

Можно было бы использовать такой дизайн таблицы:

`+---------------+
| Field         |
+---------------+
| id            |
| object_out_id |
| object_in_id  |
| qty           |
+---------------+`

..тогда отчет **А)** вытягивается из базы средствами ORM простым запросом `FLow.Objects.all()`, а для остальных отчетов пришлось бы использовать не самые простые SQL запросы, с которыми ORM не справится.

**Второй вариант**
записывать одно перемещение бункера в две строки в базе. 

`+----------------+
| Field          |
+----------------+
| id             |
| transaction_id |
| object_id      |
| qty            |
+----------------+`

С большинством запросов тогда справится ORM, все работает быстро, НО - отчет А) как на рисунке простым запросом не вытянуть...
Хочется его сериализовать в JSON средствами Django REST Framework.
RAW запросы в DRF не поддерживают пагинацию..

Посоветуйте, какую модель хранения данных выбрать, что бы не было проблем с выводом в JSON отчета А) и при больших объемах данных не было слишком долгих обработок для прочих запросов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так...
Если типы объектов известны заранее и неизменны, то в таблице `Object` поле `type_id` лучше сделать с `choices`. Если нет, то сойдет и таблица:

### Type - типы объектов

id
name

### Object - объекты

id
name
type_id
count - количество объектов на данный момент

### Transaction - транзакции

id
date
object_id_1
object_id_2
count

При записи (изменении, удалении) транзакции увеличиваете/уменьшаете `count` в связаных оъектах.
Все нужные Вам запросы тривиальны.
(имена таблиц даны только для примера, в Django, возможно, придется использовать другие)

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Подскажите, в предлагаемой таблице "Object - объекты" count - количество объектов на данный момент где? имеется ввиду сколько на этом объекте в данный момент находится "бункеров"?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Только еще один момент - у Вас, наверняка есть регламент, согласно которого происходит управления транзакциями. То есть у транзакций должно быть еще одно поле - статус. Оно поможет понять - где находятся бункеры, которые сейчас "грузятся/разгружаются". Ведь, по идее, бункеры с объектов надо уже списывать после начала транзакции, а записывать на объект-получатель только после ее завершения.

Comment: Может быть даже более правильно, для этих целей использовать поля datetime: datetime_start (вместо date) и datetime_end. Тогда, при выборе из таблицы транзакций записей с datetime_end = None - можно получить количество бункеров которые сейчас находятся "между" объектами.

Comment: для учета состояния "между" объектами мы ввели транспорт как сами объекты. т.е. в примере с портами - это лодки. времени нахождения между одним объектом и вторым практически нет.

Comment: ..еще интересен вопрос - если появляются **типы бункеров**, то в таблице Объектов (где хранятся остатки) для каждого типа бункера придется добавлять колонку.. или лучше отдельную таблицу (объект_id, тип_бункера_id, остаток) ?  учитывая,что объектов ~5000 и видов бункеров всего 6-7..

Comment: Если типов сущности немного и они неизменны, то лучше choices селать для поля. А "Иконки" "Название" или т.п. хранить в константах в коде программы.

Comment: Вы все правильно сделали когда распространили тип "объект" и на лодки (суда). Ведь любой объект у вас имеет место для хранения бункеров, и имеет возможность передать его любому другому объекту.

Comment: А по поводу Транзакци - это состояние бункеров в момент передачи. Транзакция в любом случае не моментальна. То есть, может получиться случай, когда на одном из объектов не будет нужного количества бункеров. Понимаете о чем я? Поэтому, при начале транзакции уже надо списать бункеры с объекта-отправителя, а записать на объект-получатель бункеры можно только после окончания транзакции.